# Trying to update Progress bar in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to update my progress bar but it will not let me doing while in the function called updateProgressBar();

```
 function updateProgressBar(baby_due_date) {
    window.location.href = "../../home.html";
    //40 weeks of pregnancy
    //Setting todays date
    var todays_date = new Date();
    //Finding the difference bewtween the dates by milli sec.
    var date_difference = baby_due_date - todays_date;
    //Converting millisecs to weeks
    var weeks_Left_unil_baby = Math.ceil(date_difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7));
    //Updating how many weeks are left on HTML

    //Finding the progress of the pregnancy by percent
    var progress_percent = (1 - (weeks_Left_unil_baby / 40)) * 100;
    console.log(progress_percent);

    //TODO: need to update progress here  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    $('#progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', '100%')
    progress_bar_classes.width('100%');
}
```

here is my html.

```
<div class="progress bg-secondary">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="25%" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
```

here is my CSS.

```
div.progress-bar {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to debug your code but it is not complete enough to debug it completely. I got stuck when `progress_bar_classes is not defined` came up.

Anyway here are some things that might be the problem:

- For me the progress bar height was 0 by default so i could not see it.
- `$('#progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', '100%')` Here you are refering to an element with the **id** `progress-bar` in the html code however there is only an element with a **class** `progress-bar`
- `$('#progress-bar')` The `$()` can only be used if you also include jquery.

Comment: Sorry i had tried using an ID with the same name and for got to change it over to the class, and progress-bar-class was just a variable for holding th jquery dom object of the classes from the html. It would let me change the width outside of the function, so im thinking it is a scoping issue...